Why the wavefunction phases change under different environments?
The image below shows the LUMO (lowest unoccupied molecular orbital) representation of a molecule in gas phase and under several solvent environments. The calculations were done with ORCA with B3LYP/DEF2-TZVP level of theory.
My question is: Why the wavefunction phases change under different environments?


Just a brief comment upon leeman's excellent answer.
The arbitrary sign of the MOs in different environments has something to do with the matrix diagonalization algorithm. ORCA uses the LAPACK library for diagonalizing the Fock matrix $F$:
$$
FC=\epsilon SC
$$
This is a symmetric generalized eigenvalue problem, which can either be solved directly by the LAPACK subroutine DSYGV, or solved after transforming it to the Löwdin orthogonal AO (OAO) basis and then using the subroutine DSYEV. But DSYGV internally works by performing a Cholesky decomposition of the overlap matrix $S$, and then using the Cholesky factors to transform the problem into an ordinary eigenvalue problem; therefore, in both cases eventually DSYEV is called, and the phase ambiguity occurs within DSYEV.
Let's look deeper into what DSYEV does. The standard implementation of DSYEV transforms the to-be-diagonalized matrix into the tridiagonal form (subroutine DSYTRD) using a series of Householder transformations. This is where the arbitrariness of sign kicks in. From the linked page you can see that the Householder transformation algorithm for making a matrix tridiagonal involves the sign function, applied on the off-diagonal matrix elements. Therefore, if an off-diagonal matrix element of the OAO-basis Fock matrix (or the Fock matrix transformed by Cholesky factors) changes sign, this may cause a big change of the resulting tridiagonal matrix, and therefore the signs of the resulting eigenvectors. As there are plenty of near-zero (or even exactly zero) Fock matrix elements in a typical matrix, and there may be more near-zero matrix elements in the intermediate matrices generated during the Householder transformations, it may well be that a very tiny change of the solvent, or geometry, will flip the sign of a Fock matrix element, and make the final orbital signs completely different.
In fact, the orbital signs are so sensitive to the computation details that even the following factors will often change the orbital signs:

The initial guess. If you read the converged SCF orbitals and iterate one more step, you frequently find that the orbitals have different signs than you started from. This is because the Fock matrix that you build from the converged SCF orbitals is only identical to the converged Fock matrix up to the SCF convergence threshold (say $10^{-10}$ to $10^{-8}$), but not up to floating point precision ($10^{-16}$).
Tiny irreproducibility issues due to parallelization. When you parallelize a calculation, the results may be non-deterministic on the level of floating point precision (i.e. different runs of the same function may give differences on the level of $10^{-14}$ to $10^{-16}$). But this can be magnified into a sign flipping of many orbitals, if the irreproducibility happens on a Fock matrix element that is essentially zero.

Finally, note that DSYEV is not the only matrix diagonalization algorithm. The BDF program, for example, implemented the bottom-up least-change algorithm which finds the orbitals that block-diagonalize the Fock matrix of a given SCF iteration, while resembling the orbitals of the previous SCF iteration as much as possible, including their signs. The algorithm was designed for localized molecular orbitals (LMOs), but can also be used with the usual canonical molecular orbitals (CMOs). Using this algorithm, and using the same initial guess orbitals for all the calculations that you perform, you will get the same orbital signs regardless of solvent.

This is a good question, and a topic that I also often find confusing.
The simple answer is that the phase is not changing; all 5 orbitals are equivalent (except for minor changes to the distribution brought on by the different solvent environments).
The 'sign' or phase of a wavefunction has no absolute meaning, it only indicates a relative change in phase between different parts of the same wavefunction. This means we cannot take two separate unrelated wavefunctions, compare the 'sign' of each of them, and conclude that they are the same or different phase at that point. If you think about it, this does actually make sense. If we wanted to combine two 1s orbitals to make dihydrogen for example, we don't need to consider the 'absolute phase' of each orbital before hand. There's no such thing as a positive or negative 1s orbital (thankfully).
Within each wavefunction (orbital in this case), which phase gets to be positive and which negative is entirely up to the calculation program. It's unlikely to be actually random, but from our point of view it might as well be. Likewise which lobes we colour blue or red (or any other colour) is entirely up to us, there's no need to be consistent between different orbitals (because the positive and negative signs already have no meaning), so feel free to switch the colours so they all match if you like.
As to why your program has decided to switch the signs of the orbital lobes between the different solvents, this is harder to answer I'm afraid. I'd guess that some subtle difference in the electronics is causing the molecule to be flipped internally or something like this, but I really don't know. Which version of ORCA is this? One of the devs might be able to offer more insight.
